# SOQL - Find parents that have children only.

Tags: soql

Ok, I am out of practice and can't figure this out. I want to get just BCS__c records that have an associated Employment_Process__c record that meets the criteria. Right now I am getting all records from BCS__c.

```
Date D1 = Date.today() - 30;

        //Build Hub List
        list<BCS__c>     theHubs    = new list<BCS__c>();
        theHubs                     = [Select ID,Name,User__c,(Select Hub_Name__c
                                                       FROM Employment_Processes__r
                                                       WHERE Is_Employee_a_Referral__c = 'Yes'
                                                       AND  Actual_Start_Date__c = :D1)
                                       FROM BCS__c];

FOR(BCS__c b:theHubs){
yada yada
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In classic form I figured it out after posting it!

```
Date D1 = Date.today() - 30;

    //Build Hub List
    list<BCS__c>     theHubs    = new list<BCS__c>();
    theHubs                     = [Select ID,Name,User__c
                                   FROM BCS__c
                                   WHERE Id IN (Select Hub_Name__c
                                         FROM Employment_Processes__c
                                         WHERE Is_Employee_a_Referral__c = 'Yes'
                                         AND  Actual_Start_Date__c = :D1)
                                   ];
```

Comment: `= new list<BCS__c>();` is not necessary, by the way.